# How do I to POST info about a Youtube video's chapters via API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Youtube added the ability to break up their videos in the progress bar into sections called "chapters". As seen here [Video Chapters](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9884579?hl=en)

I would like to post a video via API and add chapters, I have not been able to find any documentation or example in the API about this.

Comment: As far as I know video chapters rely only on the description (cf the link you specified). So have you just tried editing the YouTube video description via the [Videos: update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) endpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

This method is not currently available in the YouTube Data api, it appears to just be part of YouTube studio.

YOu may want to add a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) maybe its something they will add to the api.